# onClick add propertie to jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

sample thing but I'm stuck.

I want onClick add the propertie color="primary" to the element 
I tried with onClick but I missed somthing it didn't works someone have an exemple maybe ?

```
    export default function TestButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();
 // const { room } = useVideoContext();

  return (
    <Tooltip title={'Test'} >
      <Fab className={classes.fab} > //Here !
        <RecordVoiceOverSharpIcon />
      </Fab>
    </Tooltip>
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onClick` function.

```
export default function TestButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Tooltip title={'Test'} >
      <Fab className={classes.fab} onClick={()=>{
         console.log('Clicked....')}}> //Here !
        <RecordVoiceOverSharpIcon />
      </Fab>
    </Tooltip>
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `onclick` either in `Tooltip` or `Fab` component. Try it out. Hope it will work.

```
export default function SimpleTooltips() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState('primary')
  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip title="Add" aria-label="add">
        <Fab color={color} className={classes.fab} onClick={() => setColor('secondary')}>
          <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | "default" | "secondary" | "primary" | undefined'.